# Relation between $\text{Pic}(X)$ and $\text{Cl}(X)$ in singular varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a variety (irreducible, by Hartshorne's definition).

I know that when $X$ is non-singular, the Picard group $\text{Pic}(X)$ coincides with the divisor class group $\text{Cl}(X)$. This can be seen by considering the following group homomorphism:
\begin{align*}
\gamma:\text{CaDiv}(X)&\to \text{Div}(X)\\
\{(U_i,f_i)\}_i&\mapsto \sum_{Y}n_YY
\end{align*}
where $Y$ runs through all codimension $1$ subvarieties of $X$ and $n_Y$ is the order of $f_i$ with respect to the codimension $1$ subvariety $U_i\cap Y\subset U_i$ (for some $i$ with $U_i\cap Y\neq \emptyset$, of course).

Since $X$ is non-singular, every Weil divisor can be represented as a Cartier divisor, therefore $\gamma$ is surjective. Furthermore, principal divisors are preserved under $\gamma$, so $\gamma$ induces an isomorphism $\text{Pic}(X)\simeq \text{Cl}(X)$.

But what happens in non-singular varieties?

Take for example Hartshothe's example $6.11.3$, where $X=Z(xy-z^2)\subset \mathbb{A}^3$, where $Y=Z(x,z)$ defines a Weil divisor but not a Cartier divisor (because it is not locally principle around the origin).

In this case, clearly $\gamma$ is not surjective. But we still have an inclusion $\text{Pic}(X)\hookrightarrow \text{Cl}(X)$, don't we? Can we say in general that $\text{Pic}(X)$ is a subgroup of $\text{Cl}(X)$?

Comment: Weil divisors are codimension 1 subvarieties, while Cartier divisors are codimension 1 subvarieties that can be locally defined by a single equation. This implies CDiv always embbeds into WDiv. Now, principal Weil divisors are Cartier (being globally defined by a single equation), so that the inclusion is always preserved after you take the quotient.

Comment: @user347489, one more thing has just occured do me: if $X$ is non-singular, we still should assume the set of singularities $X^\text{sing}$ has codimension $\geq 2$ in $X$, shouldn't we?

Comment: otherwise I think we would have trouble defining $n_Y=\text{ord}_Y(f_i)$

Comment: yeah, doesn't Hartshorne require regular in codimension one to even define these objects? I don't know if it's possible to be more general.

Comment: I recommend reading §2.1 in Fulton's *Intersection theory*. There is a way to define the numbers $n_Y$ (in your notation) that makes your map $\gamma$ work for non-normal varieties. If $X$ is normal, then $\gamma$ is injective, but otherwise it is often not; see Fulton's book. The other thing to mention is that I don't know exactly what you mean by the Picard group, but the group of isomorphism classes of line bundles is not in general the same as Cartier divisors up to linear equivalence; see the discussion around Example 1.1.5 in Lazarsfeld's *Positivity in algebraic geometry I*.